# Why did Pi-4's port layout change?

Tags: usb, pi-4, hardware, ethernet-port, case

If you look at a Raspberry Pi 4 B from <strike>port side</strike> the side of the USB ports, it's a striking difference to previous B-models that USB block and ethernet jack have switched places.

To me this is a slight inconvenience, since I often blindly plug USB devices into the Pi, now resulting for the sixteenth time in me jamming a thumb drive into the ethernet port, and wondering why it wouldn't show up in /dev.

This results in my question: **Why was this specific layout-change implemented?**

I can imagine two reasons here:

- Technical reasons - the PCB layout had to be changed due to demands from USB3.0 or Gb-ethernet.

To prevent people from shoving the Pi into an old Pi-3 case and thereby blocking (or damaging the USB-C power port.

...or is there even something completely different to the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the launch announcement it was to simplify routing:

> Our Gigabit Ethernet magjack has moved to the top right of the board, from the bottom right, greatly simplifying PCB routing.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-on-sale-now-from-35/